# How to add/insert a value to the end of an array programmatically (in the .theme file) Add a $row

Tags: views, theming

I have some code in the .theme file that renders an array list.  I wish to add one additional entry at the end.

I found I could do that with a quick and dirty PHP `echo` statement, and it works just fine, but I would love to know the right way to do this, how to actually insert an entry at the end, one additional `$row` after all the others.  Here's my code so far (that works, but seems inelegant).

```
function csurg_barrio_preprocess_views_view_summary_unformatted(&$variables) {
    $view = variables['view'];
    $view_display_id = $view->getDisplay()->display['id'];

    if ($view->id() === 'content_display' && $view_display_id === 'attachment_1') { // create a list of filters from a to z
        $rows = $variables['rows'];
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            // kint($row);
            $url = $row->url;
            $link = $row->link;
            $wanted_url = '/conditions-and-treatments/' . $link;
            if ($url !== $wanted_url) {
                $row->url = $wanted_url;
            }
        }
        // append a value to the end of the list
        // $url = "/conditions-and-treatments/all";
        // $link = "Full List";
        // $row->url = $url;
        // the below works but is not particularly elegant
        echo '<span class="views-filter-all-option views-summary views-summary-unformatted">&nbsp;| <a href="/conditions-and-treatments/all">Full List</a></span>';
    }

}
```

What's a better way to achieve this?
[image: Screenshot from VSCode]

Comment: Don't `echo`. Instead add the markup or a render element to the `$variables` (e.g. `$variables['foobar']` and then print it in your template (e.g. `{{ foobar }}`).